# How to write unit test for ipcRenderer.on and ipcRenderer.send in Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, electron, enzyme

Hi I have developing a project using Electron and React,

I have a form in react side which on submit calls the `ipcRenderer.on` an `ipcRenderer.send` method.

I am having difficulty writing unit test code for form submit function. the function is as follows.

```
  handleFormSubmit = () => {
    const ethData = this.state.data;
    ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', (event, arg) => {
      if (arg === 'success') {
        this.setState({ status: true });
      }
    });
    ipcRenderer.send('update', value);
  }
```

First i just wanted to test that on click of save button handleFormSubmit function is called.
What I wrote is -

```
it('calls handleFormSubmit method when the form is submitted', () => {
  const instance = wrapped.instance();
  wrapped.find('button').simulate('click');
  expect(instance.handleFormSubmit()).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

The error I am getting is

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the unit test solution:

`index.jsx`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

class SomeComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: '', status: false };
  }
  handleFormSubmit = () => {
    const ethData = this.state.data;
    const value = 'value';
    ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', (event, arg) => {
      if (arg === 'success') {
        this.setState({ status: true });
      }
    });
    ipcRenderer.send('update', value);
  };
  render() {
    return <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}></form>;
  }
}

export default SomeComponent;
```

`index.test.jsx`:

```js
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import SomeComponent from '.';
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

jest.mock(
  'electron',
  () => {
    const mElectron = { ipcRenderer: { on: jest.fn(), send: jest.fn() } };
    return mElectron;
  },
  { virtual: true },
);

describe('59934084', () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<SomeComponent></SomeComponent>);
  });
  it('should render', () => {
    expect(wrapper.exists).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should handle submit, set status to true', () => {
    ipcRenderer.on.mockImplementationOnce((event, callback) => {
      callback(event, 'success');
    });
    wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit');
    expect(wrapper.state('status')).toBeTruthy();
    expect(ipcRenderer.on).toBeCalledWith('asynchronous-reply', expect.any(Function));
    expect(ipcRenderer.send).toBeCalledWith('update', 'value');
  });
  it('should handle submit without setting status to true', () => {
    ipcRenderer.on.mockImplementationOnce((event, callback) => {
      callback(event, 'failure');
    });
    wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit');
    expect(wrapper.state('status')).toBeFalsy();
    expect(ipcRenderer.on).toBeCalledWith('asynchronous-reply', expect.any(Function));
    expect(ipcRenderer.send).toBeCalledWith('update', 'value');
  });
});
```

Unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59934084/index.test.jsx (14.089s)
  59934084
    ✓ should render (22ms)
    ✓ should handle submit, set status to true (14ms)
    ✓ should handle submit without setting status to true (4ms)

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.jsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        16.114s, estimated 19s
```

You don't need to pass `{ virtual: true }` options to `jest.mock()` method if you installed the `electron` node module. Just remove it. The reason I use this option is I don't install the `electron` node module and make an example for you.

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59934084

Comment: I am still getting the error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined. The only difference is that in my index.jsx file I am importing ipcRenderer as  const ipcRenderer = window.ipcRenderer;  And then I have a preload.js file where I have the code like - window.ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
I load this preload file in my electron,js file when I create a new BrowserWindow.